# issue running my app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have completed my first application and debugger shows no issue in my code but as soon as I run the program, it is paused and shows the 'Thread 1: signal SIGABRT' error in my main.m file. And when I look at the simulator, it was stuck and showed two status bars one over the other (grey styled over the black styled). I simply can't find the bug in my code! I used black opaque styled status bar for my app. I did this in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`method of app delegate:

```
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

Please help!

Comment: So you get any additional error output?

Comment: Post your main.m file and your app delegate class please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I solved the problem, I had an outlet connected to one of the UIButton objects. But I had removed this outlets definition from my viewController but the connection was still there in the nib. I removed the connection from the nib and everything is working fine.